# Custom Google Maps styling for Android

Tags: android, coding-style, google-maps-api-3

This one is pretty out there, but I can't find any posts addressing it anywhere.  For Google Maps API v3, you can add custom styling to the map elements:

```
var pinkParksStyles = [
{
 featureType: "all",
 stylers: [
  { saturation: -80 }
 ]
},
{
 featureType: "poi.park",
 stylers: [
  { hue: "#ff0023" },
  { saturation: 40 }
 ]
}
];

map.setOptions({styles: pinkParksStyles});
```

Does anyone know of any way to apply custom styling to an Android MapView??  Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My initial thoughts would be to subclass MapView and override the on draw event. Have the onDraw event replace the colors in the canvas using a combination of [ColorMatrixColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrixColorFilter.html) and [AvoidXfermode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/AvoidXfermode.html). Thees should help as well:

[avoidxfermode to replace a color on canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071371/avoidxfermode-to-replace-a-color-on-canvas)

[How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, thats a good start.  I'm really interested in being able to style certain elements of the map, i.e. make the streets blue and the buildings pink (you can do this in api 3!)

Comment: @riotopsys .onDraw seems to be a final method, any further suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if I answer old post but maybe it will help someone in future. As far as I know The Google Maps Android API does not support custom styles. You can check it out there https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite. cmiiw