# Android: Customization of Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I customize the appearance of Google Maps in my Android app? 
The task is to put saturation value to 0.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Mr Zimogorov,
Perhaps a quick [search on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058787/custom-google-maps-styling-for-android) would yield your answer -- untested:

```
var pinkParksStyles = [
  {
  featureType: "all",
  stylers: [
  { saturation: 0 }
 ]
},
];

map.setOptions({styles: pinkParksStyles});
```

Comment: Dear hd1, this code refers to Google Maps API v.3. My problem is to do the same thing to Android MapView.

Answer (score 0):

@Vladimir Zimogorov

Are you talking about MapView or GoogleMapsAPI-v3? Google Maps API v3 supports "styledMapType" which enables you to control appearance of Google Maps, Mr.hd1 show an example.
Meanwhile, I think MapView haven't support the future yet.

Comment: In Google IO app the map is customized, so I believe, there must be a way to style MapView. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.iosched&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd Thank you!