# How to change color of Google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

Here I'm trying to changing the color of google map into black from white but not getting a good solution.  I tried it to change by using a relative layout over it but it hides that part , it doesn't change color of `GoogleMap`.

```
            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Comment: means which color you want to change?

Comment: You may want to check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058787/custom-google-maps-styling-for-android).

Comment: Please don't add "Solved: " to question's titles. You can indicate that your problem was solved by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution of it by running a `Html` file of Google Map in `WebView` by putting that html file into assets folder. And I used following code to display

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Panoramio Layer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
    }
    #panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    }
    #photo-panel {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
    display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=panoramio"></script>
<script>
function initializeGmaps() {
var LatLng = {lat: 28.596979, lng: 77.326742};
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('google-map');
var mapOptions = {
center : LatLng,
scrollwheel : false,
zoom : 14,
mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
backgroundColor: 'none',
styles : [{
stylers: [
{ invert_lightness: true },
{ hue: '#666' },
{ saturation: -100 },
{ lightness: -0 },
{ visibility: 'simplified' }
]
}]
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: LatLng,
map: map,
icon: '<?=base_url();?>images/marker.png',
title: 'Advisorymandi.com Pvt. Ltd.'
});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initializeGmaps);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="photo-panel">
<li><strong>Photos clicked</strong></li>
</ul>
<div id="google-map" class="youplay-gmaps" style=" height: 450px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Go here: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/
Find your style and get json for your style value and copy.
Come to your android map project resource, click-new file, add json and paste style json value like style_map.json and your map activity's `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` do this:

```
mGoogleMap = googleMap;
MapStyleOptions mapStyleOptions = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json);
mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(mapStyleOptions);
```

It works for me :)

Comment: how can i get R.raw.style_json

Answer (score -1):

For that you have to use google map v3 library. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=en)

Comment: Why doesn't it have easy steps to implement it?

Comment: You are wrong! That is Android code, and you are talking about Javascript API, which is completely different thing.

Comment: Yes. It's not related to Android.

Comment: There is no api for android to customize mapview. You should javascript to customize map.

Comment: That is the javascript api rather than the Android implementation.